# What is the most efficient way to measure the width of text on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8

DirectX on Windows Phone 8 lacks DirectWrite support, so that cannot be used for text measuring.

I know that it is possible to measure text by instantiating a `TextBlock` (or possibly a `Glyphs`) and get its `ActualWidth`, but that is a very slow solution, and what's worse, it can only be used from the UI thread.

I thought about measuring and building a cache from the width of every character, and then measure words by summing up the widths of its characters, but this approach does not take into account kerning and ligatures, thus can lead to incorrect results.

Is there any other efficient way on WP8 to measure text?

Comment: Do you have to measure text so often that the performance actually matters?

Comment: Yes! It's the absolute performance bottleneck of the app.